# unable to open browser using selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu, firefox

I am trying to open firefox/chrome through selenium but am getting errors.

I am currently on 32-bit ubuntu 14.04 and am very new to selenium.

I have installed selenium version 3.4.3

I have also installed chromedriver version 2.26 and have installed geckodriver in the right usr/loc/bin.

I am running Chrome ver. 52.xx and Firefox ver 49.0

Now when I try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

And when I try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 53.0.2785.0
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436383 (d0824d41df30c55dc5e0eff765aadf348a631aae),platform=Linux 3.13.0-86-generic x86)
```

AFAIK, there is no new Chrome for 32-bit Ubuntu and I cannot figure out how to solve the error with Firefox. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: read this https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/

Comment: I followed this guide to set everything up. He has a 64bit ubuntu so can run the latest chrome. but since mine is 32bit, i can't update my chrome.

Comment: As you are using `chromedriver version 2.26` the error says it all `WebDriverException: .... : Chrome version must be >= 53.0.2785.0` Thanks

Comment: I know that. There is no new version for 32bit ubuntu.

Comment: So you should downgrade browser, there is no other way) As each driver version supports only specific browser versions. If you installed last driver and new chrome is not yet supported by it - you should keep chrome downgraded until new driver come up.

Comment: Which version of chromedriver would work for chrome 52? Its difficult to identify from their changelog